# Why is `Alpha Over` compositor no longer blending values between 0 and 1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

I have the following compositor nodes, that are supposed to add a white background behind my transparent render layer (using setting `Render Properties` -> `Film` -> `Transparent`).

[image]

Unfortunately the result only seems to be looking at either 0% alpha or 100% alpha, no blending for the intermediate values:

[image]

If I remove the alpha-over node and just save the image as RGBA, the alpha channel looks correct, and if I add a white background manually (using GIMP or imagemagick), It is correctly showing behind it:

[image]

The weirdest thing is, if I remove the `Alpha-Fac` connection, and just set the factor to 0.5, it composites the whole image to white. (Instead of multiplying the foreground image's alpha by 0.5, as one would expect when reading the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html).)

This used to work before, but since I recently edited my World-background-shader-nodes, the alpha-over broke. But according to the image above, my alpha-layer is fine. Is this a bug in Blender?

Comment: Change the alpha over colour. Guessing the reflections show up?

Comment: I tried a few more things, and it looks like it always happens when I use an *.exr file for my hdr map. If I use a jpeg for my environment texture the background is correctly blended.

Comment: @troy_s the color just changed the background color, not the fact that alpha is not taken into account.

Comment: If it is a render, the alpha is taken into account. The only method to preserve the correct encoding is EXR. PNG cannot support reflections, etc.

Comment: So, what I did to fix the issue is convert my hdr.exr to hdr.jpg, after doing this the renders that I created had the correct alpha values.

Comment: Not a chance. Post the EXR from the render.